# Compare two columns in different workbooks

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I would appreciated if I can get some help on an issue trying to create a vba macro. I have two workbooks and I want to compare column "N" in workbook 1 to column "F" in workbook 2. Then if there's a match move to the next cell down if no matches were found I want to copy the next cell after column "F" in workbook 2. Workbook 2 will not have the same name when I get it each morning but the workbook name always starts with "Copy of" so I created the code below to select it by using partial name.

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name Like "Copy of*" Then
        ws.Select
        Exit For
    End If
Next ws
```

Even If I can get pointed to the right direction that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This explanation is not very clear

> ...if there's a match move to the next cell down if no matches were
>   found I want to copy the next cell after column "F" in workbook 2...

but try something like this, and modify it accordingly

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CompareWorkBooks()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = GetWSCopy("Copy of*")

    If Not ws2 Is Nothing Then

        Dim r As Long, cel As Range, found As Variant, ws2lr As Long

        optimizeXL True
        For r = ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            Set cel = ws1.Cells(r, ws1.Columns("N").Column)
            If Len(cel.Value2) > 0 Then
                found = Application.Match(cel.Value2, ws2.UsedRange.Columns("F"), 0)

                If Not IsError(found) Then  'a match was found so move next cell down
                    cel.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert xlDown
                Else    'match not found so copy row from ws1 to first empty row of ws2
                    ws2lr = ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
                    ws1.UsedRange.Rows(cel.Row).EntireRow.Copy ws2.Cells(ws2lr, 1)
                End If
            End If
        Next
        optimizeXL False
    End If
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Function GetWSCopy(ByVal wsName As String) As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name Like wsName Then
            Set GetWSCopy = ws
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function

Public Sub optimizeXL(Optional ByVal settingsOff As Boolean = True)
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = Not settingsOff
        .Calculation = IIf(settingsOff, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
        .EnableEvents = Not settingsOff
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Also, you are referring to 2 Workbooks (files),
but your code refers to Worksheets (Tabs within the same Workbook)